# Team Foundation Server 2010 - Activity Reports

Tags: tfs-reports

We are rolling out a global instance of TFS 2010 in our organisation which will be used both internally and externally (vendors).  I'd like to be able to get some reports of the daily activity across all the Team Project Collections and Team Projects for things like:

- Total number of Team Projects
- Total number of Checkins/changesets per day/month/etc
- Total number of bugs/issues logged per day/month/etc
- Total number of bugs/issues resolved per day/month/etc
- Datbase sizes for Team Project Collections

This information will be incrediably useful to help understand what the uptake and usage is like.  It will also help to plan when/how we are going to need to scale our environment.

What's the best way to acheive this?  Building my own custom reports in SSRS?  Creating custom web parts for our integrated SharePoint environment? Or, are there any products out there that can help?